# DynamoDB: Delete items before update

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Here is my Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({region: "ap-southeast-2"});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

var tableName = "MyTable1";

dynamodb.updateItem({
    "TableName": tableName,
    "Key": {
        "sub": {
            "S": event.sub
        }
    },

    "UpdateExpression": "ADD EventID :val1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":val1": {
            "SS": event.EventID
        }
    },

    "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW",
}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        context.fail('ERROR: Dynamo failed: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Dynamo Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
        context.succeed('SUCCESS');
    }
});
```

}

The code works fine when I am adding or inserting new items.

What I want to do is delete the items first, before I can do an update ?

I tried to change the UpdateExpression by replacing ADD with SET

```
 "UpdateExpression": "SET EventID :val1",
```

But then it gives Syntax error.

Does anyone what is the best way to delete the items before doing an update ?

So for example, if I have this data in DymnamoDB

```
ID      EventID
789534  { "BA345", "GA932", "TA900" }
```

After the new update with the following data

```
ID      EventID
789534  { "CA345"}
```

it becomes

```
ID      EventID
789534  { "CA345"}
```

So essentially every update should act like a fresh/initial add.

If anything is not clear, please feel free to ask. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to replace the item completely, you need to use `PutItem` instead of `UpdateItem`. The difference between the two is that

- PutItem will add new item if not present and *replaces* the item if found
- UpdateItem will add new item if not present and *update* the item if found. This can also add new fields to existing item.

The [API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Operations.html) has a more thorough explanation of these and other actions.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried PutItem and got this `  "errorMessage": "ERROR: Dynamo failed: MultipleValidationErrors: There were 3 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Item' in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Key' found in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'UpdateExpression' found in params"`

Comment: Check the syntax of `PutItem` from your db client documentation. It is somewhat different from update. For one, you need to use `Item` instead of `Key`. And probably remove the `UpdateExpression`, since you are not updating anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to find a sample code in NodeJS for PutItem, but so far no luck.

Comment: [Try this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property) By the way, AWS has also [another client for JavaScript with simpler API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) that is at least worth checking.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction, I was able to solve it using this code example https://gist.github.com/markusklems/1e7218d76d7583f1f7b3